Review our technology options for the 2024 Developer Survey

Update on May 6th, 2024: Thank you for taking time to share your feedback for the upcoming survey.  We have concluded reviewing these suggestions.

The time has come to ask you to vet our latest suggestions for the top technologies and tools we plan to include on the next annual Developer Survey. You can find the options we used last year on our survey site, and below you will find the additions and removals from the various sections we have planned so far.
Some options were selected for removal based on low response rates or downward trajectories in usage trends from other sources. We have proposed adding options that were common write-in answers on last year’s survey, are of interest based on our industry knowledge, or otherwise demonstrated meaningful upward trajectories in usage such as on GitHub.
There is, however, an art to the science here. Take for example Ruby on Rails: while it shows a decreasing share of responses over time, the Ruby language is also popular (ranked 17th in the 2023 survey and on the popular tag list, so it seems worthwhile to keep.
While we are reviewing your answers here, we are looking for upvotes and any supporting documentation you have to support your suggestion (think data, news sources, first-hand experience, etc.).  We may respond to some answers, time permitting.
We are looking forward to kicking off the 14th annual Stack Overflow Developer Survey next month and your feedback here is really beneficial. We will be collecting feedback until Friday, May 3, 2024.
Languages

Add: MicroPython, V (vlang)
Remove: SAS, Raku, APL, Flow

Databases

Add: EventStoreDB, Presto, Databricks SQL
Remove: No removals.

Platforms

Add: Databricks, Alibaba Cloud, PythonAnywhere
Remove: No removals.

Web Technologies

Add: Strapi, Yii 2
Remove: Lit, Qwik

Other Technologies and Libraries

Add: OpenCL, DirectX, mlflow, Roslyn
Remove: Micronaut, Uno platform

Other Developer Tools

Add: No additions.
Remove: Wasmer, doctest, SCons, bandit, cppunit, Boost.Test, build2, tunit, lest, snitch, CUTE, ELFspy, liblittletest

Integrated Developer Environments

Add: Spacemacs
Remove: TextMate, Micro, Nova, condo

Asynchronous Tools

Add: Lucid, Obsidian
Remove: Wrike, Adobe Workfront, Redocly, Document360, Nuclino, Swit, Dingtalk (Teambition), Tettra, Workzone, Planview Projectplace Or Clarizen, Wimi, Cerri, Leankor

AI Search Tools

Add: Google Gemini, Komo, Claude AI, Meta AI
Remove: Google Bard AI

AI Developer Tools

Add: AskCodi, Cody, ChatGPT, Visual Studio Intellicode, Google Gemini, OpenAI Codex, Lightning AI
Remove: Adrenaline, Rubber Duck.AI


No one gives  Multi-Edit the respect it deserves. Bought a copy back in '97 and still using it.

Best answer from last years review of the Survey. "What is AI?"

They could do with a question like "Which option do you pick in a survey when you need none of the above?" First/Last/Random? I was once coached on how to answer surveys -  always pick the extreme options and the neutral option otherwise because the 2/10 and 3/10 would take too long to honestly assess and are useless to the marketer anyway.

Bing AI is worth adding to the AI search tools.

So essentially this is going to be yet another web developer survey like always, but now spiced with a bit of AI hype. None of this is the slightest relevant to me or the other 10-15% of the user base who in previous surveys claimed to work with embedded systems. I'm tired of pointing this out year after year - I'm just going to skip this survey from now on.

Why are you dropping Lit and Qwik?

Why drop Raku? Did it change its name back to Perl or something?

You're a more patient man than I, @Lundin . I think I gave up after two.

@user4581301 What's surprising is that many embedded systems programmers did very likely give up on the survey and yet they were made up a significant part of the survey participants last time.

MicroPython is for embedded systems, but it is not exactly representative. Give us Zephyr! It is hype-compliant (and is used in some of our beloved mechanical keyboards).

@PeterMortensen I very much doubt MicroPython is used professionally - nobody would add an extra bloat layer just for the heck of it.

It doesn’t make sense to include Deno and not Bun (JavaScript runtimes).

While it still has modest presence on main, Htmx has been quickly gaining popularity on GitHub, perhaps as an effect of the person writing it being quite good with memes on Twitter.
It's still a totally serious software that brings back hypermedia to the web, and finished 2nd in the 2023 JavaScript Rising Stars "Front-end Frameworks" category.
It features a quite unique "html over the wire" philosophy when compared with most of the current ecosystem which I think makes it a great candidate for inclusion in Web Technologies.

I second this. I haven't used it but it's making a big splash in the full-stack Java community.

I third this. HTMX is an amazing little library and I use it in production.

Why


Add: Spacemacs


When it is

A community-driven Emacs distribution

Or in other words, "Emacs with plugins", which already is on the list of IDEs
There is no single Vim or Neovim distribution among the IDEs when both are individually bigger than Emacs so why split Emacs when both Vim and Neovim aren't split?

Obligatory and explicit note that Vim and Neovim are, in fact, different editors. One is not a distribution of the other, even though they share parts of the same name. Neovim is based on Vim, but is a separate project with separate development goals, features, and configuration systems.  (Additional obligatory note that I'm not saying cafce25 meant to remove either vim or neovim, but we've had more than enough misunderstandings when compiling this list in the past, so this is to make sure the company doesn't misinterpret this answer as "remove neovim too")

I know that this is too much of a change and also very complex so it won't probably ever be implemented but I'll suggest it anyway.
Last year I said as a feedback on the developer survey:

Another note is that other than the Play Framework, Scala's frameworks and tools/libraries are completely missing. For example, you could have included Akka as a framework, SBT and Mill as build tools, etc.

To which Silvio Mayolo responded by saying:

Just thinking out loud, but I wonder, in the future, if they could make the "which technologies do you use" section context sensitive? Like, show all the popular Scala libraries only if you selected "Scala" as a language you use. Only show Rails if you picked Ruby, etc., etc. It would give a lot more space to collect data on libraries in that awkward category of "very popular in language X but relatively unknown outside of it", which is a very large category.

I think this is a pretty good idea and will make the survey much more relevant and insightful as the lists that are shown in the technology questions are 80% irrelevant to each participant.

Python typing seems to be gaining popularity. Please consider adding these type checkers to "Other Developer Tools":



Tool
PyPI installs last month
GitHub stars




mypy
~25M installs
~18K stars


Pyright
~2M installs
~12K stars


pytype
~496K installs
~5K stars


Pyre
~82K installs
~7K stars



Formatters/linters might be worthwhile as well. In particular, Ruff is relatively new but quickly gaining traction:



Tool
PyPI installs last month
VS Code installs




Black
~37M installs
~3M installs


Flake8
~30M installs
~772K installs


Ruff
~16M installs
~556K installs




It should be noted that Ruff is not a type checker (yet?) but a linter. For example, ruff check --select=ALL .py with .py containing a: int = '' outputs no type errors.

I'm not sure if VSCode installs are really representative, 'cause plain installs count on PyPIStats show a different picture: black got 38M installs last month, flake8 got 30M and ruff got 16.5M (almost a half of black - truly impressive for such a new tool). That number includes CI and other repeated and one-time executions, so it's a different stat, but IMO it's more meaningful than VSCode users count which is biased (only one dev environment - perhaps black is better integrated with this IDE or just shows up on top of the search).

I feel that in particular the exclusionof MyPy is a big mistake, seeing how it's so popular; also Black and Flake8.


Languages

Add: MicroPython, V (vlang)
Remove: SAS, Raku, APL, Flow



What is Flow?
Why is it being removed from the programming languages now, when it was a developer tool in 2023, a tool in 2022, and not in the survey in 2021?
Did you mean "TensorFlow" which was listed as a language in the last surveys?


Why would TensorFlow have been listed as a language before, when it's clearly a library?

@KarlKnechtel They have regularly listed things like that incorrectly over the years.

Platform
Add: Supabase
Supabase employee here. Supabase is quickly gaining popularity as a cloud platform option containing auth, database, storage, and edge functions allowing developers to create a complete application on top of it. Although Supabase was already an option for database last year, adding it as an option for platform makes sense as well.

it is an active topic on SO https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=supabase

1829 (visible) questions in the tag.

But it isn't notable enough to be on Wikipedia. Or Wikipedia can't keep up.

AI search tools
Consider removing "Bing AI" and replacing it with "Microsoft Copilot".
The terminology is beyond the scope of this answer, but it's on Wikipedia. Particularly:

Windows Copilot, which had been available in the Windows Insider Program, would be renamed to Microsoft Copilot in October when it became broadly available for customers. The same month also saw Microsoft Edge's Bing Chat function be renamed to Microsoft Copilot with Bing Chat. On November 15, 2023, Microsoft announced that Bing Chat itself was being rebranded as Microsoft Copilot.

(I've omitted formatting, including footnote citations and links)

Alternatively, call it "Microsoft Copilot (AKA Bing AI)" so people who didn't keep up with the changes in the latter half of last year don't get confused.

Great point, and I will make this update and add some language like "aka" or "formerly"

@ErinAsks Thanks! If you end up doing an "a.k.a.", it might be worth doing that for Bard/Gemini too (source), but I don't recall if it'd be appropriate in that case.

Add: conda to category: Other tools.
conda is a package management and environment management system.

Widely used package management, most commonly for Python but also beyond. What it adds on addition to pip is: a) better support for compiled non-Python dependencies, b) respecting version constraints better, many more things c) in contrast to apt etc it's cross platform, d) very little delay after upstream release (hours or days not months). It's very common in bioinformatics (our team uses it extensively) but also used in ML, data science,... When the solver got slow, a team rewrote it as mamba, and then micromamba. The ecosystem is very much alive. Thousands of contributors to packages.

Web Technologies
Add: Astro

At least as many recent questions as Yii 2, one of the other two proposed additions (besides Strapi)
42.5k GitHub stars, about 3x more than Yii 2 (14.2k), and Yii has been flattening, while Astro (in red) is accelerating, catching up with Strapi.
Visual Studio Code extension installs: Astro has >500k, while the most popular Yii extension has only ~50k

Based on the statistics above, it's unclear why Yii 2 should be added, but not Astro.


I'm a big fan of using PR Creators over Stars for measuring the health and popularity of some of the tools we ask about, I see astro here, categorized as a static site generator more specifically than a web framework but supports your case. Appreciate the visualization!

Thanks @ErinAsks! ossinsights.io is great, I wasn't aware of it. Astro seems to blow Yii2 out of the water. It's more than a static site generator, it has certain features of a static site generator but it allows embedding other more dynamic frameworks within. Maybe the exact category doesn't matter so much as the header here is Web technologies and it is unarguably one.

That context helps and makes a good case for adding to 'Web Technologies'.

That hand-drawn styling is lovely, but when scaled down, those fonts are real PITA to read. :(

@DanMašek I agree, but it was the quickest way to generate this graph for me

Regarding embedded Linux:

Yocto / BitBake
Buildroot

Are the main competing build systems. For me, it would be very interesting to gather a little data there. Searching "embedded Linux" turns up those two. Most chip vendors provide a Yocto Layer, and every professional I met used either Yocto or Buildroot for embedded Linux.
Regarding embedded in general:
With a quick Ctrl + F, I'm unable to find even high-level/hobbyist stuff like Arduino, Raspberry Pi, PlatformIO, etc. in the recent surveys.
Regarding Lundin's comment, it feels a little under-represented. I hope I'm not dropping a brick here, but maybe some trial balloon could be launched with a few popular options. If there already was one in the past, I'd be happy to learn about it.


Languages
Add: MicroPython, V (vlang)
Remove: SAS, Raku, APL, Flow

Vlang is (was?) a scam. It overpromised—with completely unrealistic goals—and underdelivered. The only thing it succeeded at was gather donations via Patreon.
The situation may have changed in the last year. Maybe. But I would like to see a convincing argument it's no longer a scam—claims in line with deliveries—before publicizing it in the survey.

I hadn't heard of V before. A quick google backs up the controversy you allude to. Here are a few discussions/posts describing it as controversial: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=31793554 https://github.com/vlang/v/issues/35 https://xeiaso.net/blog/v-vaporware-2019-06-23/ https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=20229632

@CorneliusRoemer: Yes, though I do note these posts are old. The last time I read about the disconnect between promises and reality was in 2022 I think (https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/vfsfro/v_language_review_2022/)... perhaps because nobody has tried V again since (once burnt, twice shy). The repo does seem quite active, with multiple committers, so it may be better... but then again I do follow systems programming languages closely, and never saw any "good" article about V indicating a reversal.

There are 58 questions in the V tag. That is 5 times less than Forth's; it has had a longer time, but still.

Where is V getting its hype from?

At the onset, the developer claimed that he had developed a safe systems programming language that could compile 1M lines per second. He promised to publish the source code, he just "had to clean it up" first. Folks jumped on the bandwagon.

I think the package installer/resolver uv also deserves to be mentioned in the Other tools section. It is getting more and more attention from the Python community, being created by the same company as Ruff.

And ruff itself as well!


Other Technologies and Libraries
Remove: Micronaut

Why?
Micronaut is consistently one of the recommended options for Java developers looking for microservice-oriented frameworks.
Yes, it may be not as popular as Spring Boot or Quarkus, but it's definitely in the top 3 along with them.
The problem is that it's shoved up in a too-generic category of "other libraries" where specialized frameworks like this can obviously be shadowed by gigantic monsters like .NET or Spring.
I mean, I don't even know what kind of insight whatsoever can be obtained from putting completely, orthogonally unrelated tools like .NET, Kafka, Qt and Quarkus in the same category.
But that's not my point, my point is that Micronaut is a rather popular framework in the Java world if you want to go the non-Spring route, so I don't know why it would be removed.

How about other category of AI Tools such as txt2img, img2img, and txt2vid? I understand that it does not directly relate to developer code-wise, but I, as a developer, sometimes have some needs to use other kinds of assets such as images, videos, and audio. So, if you consider this then here is a list of some options for starter.
Popular tools nowadays are (not limited to):

DALL·E
Midjourney
Adobe Firefly
Stable Diffusion Web UI (Automatic1111)

and many others...
(edits for more options are appreciated)

This is really not at all related to software development, which is what the survey is about.
